# Got my UK visa that doesn't say "visa"

Tags: visas, uk, passports, standard-visitor-visas

So my passport arrived but the vignette doesn't say "UK Visa" like my previous Schengen visa does. Instead it says "UK Entry Clearance". Others texts on the vignette however are pretty much expected and normal, such as type c visit, valid and expire dates, multi entries, etc.

Is that something to fret about?
Thanks!

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica yes! Thanks. So it'll be fine?

Comment: It'll get you to the UK border, where you'll be subject to the regular landing interview. See Traveller's comment in the linked question and answer.

Comment: A Schengen visa never says "UK visa."